# Ploting implicit variable of Nonanalytic Equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a non-analytical equation. I could solve for different values of parameters but my program is not working at all. At the end i want to plot y vs x

```
f[x_] := y + Sqrt[3 + x*y - x^20 - y^4]
Table[f[x], {x, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}] 
NSolve[f[x] == 0, y]
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be R?  Looks more like mathematica or something...

Comment: See [mathematica.se]

Comment: This is not making sense from an R perspective. Either use standard mathematical notation or change the tag, please.

Comment: yes its mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := y + Sqrt[3 + x*y - x^20 - y^4]

sol = Solve[f[x] == 0, y];

x0 = Table[i, {i, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}];
subs = N[sol /. x -> #] & /@ x0
```

This creates results from which we can see that the first and second solutions produce complex numbers.  Plotting the two real solutions first.

```
y3 = subs[[All, 3, 1, 2]];
y4 = subs[[All, 4, 1, 2]];

ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{x0, y3}], Transpose[{x0, y4}]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively the plot can be produced from the solutions with

```
Plot[{sol[[3, 1, 2]], sol[[4, 1, 2]]}, {x, 0.1, 0.5}]
```

[image]

The complex solutions can be plotted like so:

```
ParametricPlot[{{Re[sol[[1, 1, 2]]], Im[sol[[1, 1, 2]]]},
  {Re[sol[[2, 1, 2]]], Im[sol[[2, 1, 2]]]}}, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]